# Writing an inequality in set notation

Tags: inequality, notation

I'm having trouble writing a solution in set notation. Iv been asked to write an equation to describe a region from a graph but express the answer in set notation. My solution is y>x^2-4. How do I write this in set notation?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable option is $$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, y>x^2-4\}$$

Comment: Thank you this makes sense now. How about a solution like y≥x+1 or y≥2^x?

Comment: Same thing, unless otherwise requested.